# std intellisense in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

I just noticed that eclipse has a extensive intellisense for stl. If you hover over any stl function or object you get information similar to what you would find in a c++ stl reference.

This is however not the case in VS2010 and I'm wondering if there is any good plugin that might enable this? and even more far fetched... for boost as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the productivity power tools extention for vs2k10.  It has many nice things, like a replacement for the Add Reference dialog box( the new one is searchable!) and one of the thing is a replacement for the standard intellisense.

Comment: Err... how so? I don't see anything there that modifies intellisense. More importantly, most of that stuff only works for managed code.

Comment: i havn't tried it with C++ but i know it works nicely with C#, and i figured it cant hurt to give it a try.  The Add Ref. stuff wont, of course, help you.